# react-native-navigation: Trigger when screen pops up after using goBack()

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I user react-native-navigation to navigate through my react-native app.
I've got a page which shows my local stored content from which I navigate to a page where I can update my content.

When I go back after changing the content, the page still shows the "old" content because the constructor isn't triggered when the screen above uses goBack().

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As you don't provide specific code, answer is also more general.
There are several ways of achieving that.

I would suggest one of these:

1. using Context, set some trigger variable in it and access it from child screen once you update content. Usually useState. In Parent screen you got useEffect that has this variable in dependency array, so once variable changes, it triggers re-load (or whatever you define in useEffect).
2. useFocusEffect is hook provided by react navigation library that is called every time a screen where you implement it is focused.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/

In this hook you again define your re-load function and every time you come back to Parent screen (from anywhere) it will be triggered.

Comment: I think useFocusEffect is exactly what I need. But I can't find a way to implement it inside a class component. Do you know how I can do this?